# react functional component does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

function validate is supposed to return element if function getConjugation doesn't return error, the valid input is passed to getConjugation, but it just renders nothing in browser

```
import React from 'react'
import {getConjugation} from 'german-verbs'
import GermanVerbsDict from 'german-verbs-dict'

export default ({word})=>{
    const renderVerbs =(w)=>{

        return (

    }

    const validate = (w) =>{
        try{
            return(
            <ul>
               <li>{w.toLowerCase()}</li>
               <li>{getConjugation(GermanVerbsDict, "haben",'PRASENS', 2,'S' )}</li>
               <li>{getConjugation(GermanVerbsDict,"haben",'PRATERITUM', 1,'S' )}</li>
               <li>{getConjugation(GermanVerbsDict, "haben",'PERFEKT', 1,'S', "HABEN")}</li>
            </ul>)
        }catch {return false}
    }
    return (
        <div className="verb">{validate(word)}</div>


    )
}
```

Comment: The example code is wrong, and we need to know what `word` is and what `getConjugation` does

Comment: have you tried to return the items without try/catch block?

Comment: Alopwer, it works without try catch

Answer (score 0):

You may try 3 things

1. Complete the renderVerbs function since now is missing a bracket.
2. This part of code seems to be exported out. Have you added this component to where it suppose to be?
3. Check whether validate function is actually been called. Here is what I will do.

```
const validate = (w) =>{
            console.log("the word is: ", w);
            return(
            <ul>
               <li>{w.toLowerCase()}</li>
               //if your function return an array
               YourArray.map(elem => (
                  <li>{elem}</li>
               ))
            </ul>)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="verb">{validate(word)}</div>
    )
```

If it does work, add one extra block code each at a time until it comes to your original code mentioned here. Hope you may find which part is buggy in this process. Good luck.

Comment: i've just figured out, that the problem is in a function in last <li>, it returns an array of 2 string,all the other 1 string, but i still can't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: array and object cannot be directly put inside the ```{}```. React doesn't know how to render it.  you need to use the map function for it. Please check the modified answer.

Comment: What does ```getConjugation``` function return. Can you put code on fiddle or sth?